# How can I set the default shell in spacemacs (Evil mode) when executing commands in a buffer?

Tags: spacemacs, shell

I've downloaded spacemacs (configured with Evil mode) on a Windows PC and would like to use bash or wsl as the default.

**Example**:

Open the `evil-tutor` and execute command `:!ls`

**Desired Behaviour**:

I would like this command to run in bash or wsl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `shell-file-name` variable

> shell-file-name is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
>
> File name to load inferior shells from.
>
> Initialized from the SHELL environment variable, or to a system-dependent
>   default if SHELL is unset.

This variable is used in `call-process-shell-command` function that is invoked by `shell-command` interactive function. And `shell-command` is in turn used in `evil-shell-command`.